# Optimising FOR LOOP or alternative to it

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, optimization

I am using a FOR LOOP to calculate a simple probability on a dataset with approximately 500K rows of data.

***For loop***

```
class_ = 4
class_freq = Counter(list_[-1] for list_ in train_list) # Counter({5: 1476, 1: 1531, 4: 1562, 3: 1430, 2: 1498, 7: 1517, 6: 1486})


def cp(x, class_, freq_): # x is column index passed from another function
    for row in train_list:
        pos = 0
        neg = 0
        if row[x] == 1 and row[54] == class_:
            pos+=1
        else:
            neg+=1

    cal_0 = (neg + 0.1) / (class_freq[class_value] + 0.2)
    cal_1 = (pos + 0.1) / (class_freq[class_value] + 0.2)

    if prob_1 > prob_0:
        return prob_1
    else:
        return prob_0
```

***Train_list sample***

```
[3050, 180, 4, 277, -3, 5782, 221, 242, 156, 2721, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[2818, 119, 19, 30, 10, 5213, 248, 220, 92, 4497, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[3182, 115, 10, 553, 10, 4605, 237, 231, 124, 1768, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[3024, 312, 18, 474, 177, 5785, 169, 224, 194, 4961, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[3067, 32, 4, 30, -2, 6679, 219, 230, 147, 2947, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
[2716, 1, 10, 234, 27, 2100, 206, 222, 153, 5581, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
...
```

The FOR LOOP works well on small dataset (few hundred rows) as expected. Unfortunately, when I try to use it on 20K rows of data, the processing time take ages. I cannot imagine how long it will take to run 500K rows of data.

FOR LOOP is grossly bad in performance for large dataset. What is an alternative to this? Will Lambda improve processing speed? I appreciate advice and assistance here, thanks.

***Edited***:

Thanks to everyone comments, I have tried to work on another algorithm to replace the FOR LOOP.

```
def cp(x, class_, class_): 
    filtered_list = [t for t in train_list if t[54] == class_]

    count_binary = Counter(binary[col] for binary in filtered_list)
    
    binary_1 = count_binary[1]
    binary_0 = count_binary[0]

    cal_0 = (binary_0 + 0.1) / (class_freq[class_value] + 0.2)
    cal_1 = (binary_1 + 0.1) / (class_freq[class_value] + 0.2)

    if prob_1 > prob_0:
        return prob_1
    else:
        return prob_0
```

I am still running the above code in my program and the process is not done yet - so can't tell if it is much efficient. I will appreciate if someone can provide their opinion on this new block of code.

FYI, if this is indeed a better and more efficient code, then the issue of processing speed is most likely on other parts of my code.

Comment: Is the intention for this to come in as or become a numpy object?

Comment: Look for the functions `filter`, `map` and `reduce`.

Comment: There is actually no usage of numpy in this. The function will return a probability float back to a calculation function which will do the multiplication for each row. As long as the output returns a float value, using numpy will be fine.

Comment: I suppose more specifically, numpy may allow you to vectorize this operation, which avoids the (tremendous) expense of creating intermediate Python objects and can also make very efficient use of modern processor features

Comment: Your for loop wastes time looking at a lot of rows and throwing away results, and in the end only uses the result of the last row.  You should either remove the loop and process only the last row, or else fix the loop so it doesn't discard partial results when processing a new row.

Comment: Also, it seems you could pre-split the data according to either rows where row[x] == 1 for each x, or by row[54] == y for each y.  Then your loop would start with a much smaller collection of rows and only have to filter by the other constraint.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Appreciate your feedback on my edited post!

Comment: you could try to use [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) to speed the computation up if your project is quite simple (and without many dependencies). Besides this, you can also replace the `filtered_list` by a generator (using the notation `(...)` rather than `[...]`). It may not be faster but will likely consume less memory.